# Break a row of views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a `LinearLayout` container (with `horizontal` orientation) inside a `HorizontalScrollView`. This container contains a few views, let's say 8 views, of the same type.

Now, as I'm measuring the height of the HorizontalScrollView (which can vary between devices), I can determine if this (one) row of views can split into 2 rows or even 3 rows.

The question is simple: Is there a way to act on this row of views as if it was a line of text where I can 'break' the row into 2 rows or 3 rows. Ideally, if height exists to accommodate 2 rows then break row after 4th view, or if height can accommodate 3 rows then break the row after 3rd and 6th views.

**The way I'm doing it now** is that I just move the views between sub-LinearLayout containers in order to create 1, 2 or 3 rows of these views as needed.

Comment: you mean something like this: https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout ???

Comment: @SarthakMittal, I've just tested it and it could have been great under a traditional vertical scrolling, but in my case it just produces `one` row of the views because it's not limited horizontally. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Instead of a  `LinearLayout` inside the `HorizontalScrollView`, could you not use a `GridView` instead and control its layout using `GridView#setNumColumns(int)`  depending on where you want the rows to break?

Answer (score 0):

Try using horizontal recyclerview with staggered grid layout manager see if it helps or not. I think i might help as per your requirement